# Solving Simultaenous Equations and Partial Derivatives

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't have a strong math background, so any help with the below with the algebra behind the solutions below would be massively appreciated for future reference, both in terms of the algebra of simultaneous equations and the derivation of the partial derivatives.

The set of simultaneous equations is given:

$wt-c= 0, c=w(24-t)+I$

Could someone help me identify the steps towards the solutions for t and c, given below?

$t=12+\frac{I}{2w}$

And

$c= 12w+\frac{I}{2}$

Also, the partial derivatives are given:

$\frac{\partial t}{\partial w}= - \frac{I}{2w^2}<0$

And subsequently,

$\frac{\partial t}{\partial I} = \frac {1}{2w}>0$

I look forward to any responses on the matter,

Best,

Andrew

Comment: It's understandable that you may not have a super-strong math background -- nevertheless, the only way to properly learn is to give it an honest attempt yourself first. This attempt serves as a record of how you think about the problem, and it is in tweaking your own thinking that you will become better at mathematics. So be sure to edit this problem with your own attempt at a solution!

Comment: The partial derivatives are of no use.

Comment: Using $c=wt$, the second is $2wt=24w+I$. The rest is quasi-immediate.

Comment: Thank you to all answers, comments, and corrections below. Peter and Kavi, thanks for answering regardless of errors in my initial question.

Comment: Hi Yves, the partial derivatives presented below are of no practical significance in this example. However, they provide the sign of the w and I, that's why I asked how they were derived in this instance.

Comment: @AndrewCoyle: you didn't ask for the derivatives and their signs, did you ?

Comment: I stand corrected on that one Yves, you're right. I hadn't specified the question properly in terms of attaining the PDs. Thanks however for the detailed Cramer-based approach below!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the partial derivatives given. Using the initial equations we get
$$c=wt$$
$$c=24w-wt+I$$
Hence we have
$$wt=24w-wt+I$$
$$2wt=24w+I$$
$$t=12+\frac{I}{2w}$$
Then we just use
$$c=wt=12w+\frac{I}2$$
I believe there is a typo in the given value of $c$.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Much valued.

Answer (score 0):

We have $c=wt$ from the first equation. Put this into the second to get $wt=w(24-t)+I$ or $wt=24w-wt+I$. Transfer $wt$ on RHS to LHS to get $2wt=24w+I$. Divide by $2w$ to get $t=12+\frac I {2w}$. Next use $c=wt$ to get $c=w(12+\frac I {2w})=12w+\frac I 2$. So the equation you have for $c$ is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Kavi, I appreciate your help on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

**The long way:**

Setting the system of linear equations in the canonical form

$$\begin{cases}wt-c=0,\\wt+c=24w+I\end{cases}$$

you can use the Cramer's formulas

$$t=\frac{
\begin{vmatrix}0&-1\\24w+I&1\end{vmatrix}
}{
\begin{vmatrix}w&-1\\w&1\end{vmatrix}
}=\frac{24w+I}{2w}$$
$$c=\frac{
\begin{vmatrix}w&0\\w&24w+I\end{vmatrix}
}{
\begin{vmatrix}w&-1\\w&1\end{vmatrix}
}=\frac{w(24w+I)}{2w}.$$